# can't post immediately

Tags: posts, pages

something weird has happened to my sites.

i can't seem to post any page or post immediately. it says post immediately, but when i do, it instantly changes to schedule for dec 2013. I thought it was on one site, but on checking 2 more sites i have, the same thing happens.

i've checked general settings and checked the dates and time and set it to london which is where i am but not change.

really baffled, anyone?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate all plugins, does the behavior persists?

No: activate plugins one by one until you find the one causing the issues.

yes: activate twenty eleven or twenty twelve theme, does the behavior persists?

no: use a different theme.

yes: is WordPress updated? Is your server up to date with current php and mysql?

no: update previously mentioned.

yes: SOL.

Comment: done all those steps. the thing is, it's happening all 4 of my sites that i have just checked. when i check the post immediately time, it's schedule automatically for dec 2013. dunno why it's doing this?

Comment: If they are all hosted on the same server, something may be up on their end, other wise I do not know why it would effect all 4 sites. Are you running multisite? or Sharing a db?

Comment: nah, just normal wordpress installs. using bluehost, i'm waiting to speak to someone now as i'm writing this. never encountered this problem until now. i can post immediately if i change the time to the past, but that's annoying. thanks for the help though

Comment: no problem. Hopefully you get it resolved. Would bet money that somewhere someone has a time setting mis configured. It amazing how crucial time stamps are in computing processes.

Comment: i know......bluehost recently changed their wordpress installer to a third party. i'm guessing it's them, cos everything was fine before. thanks mate